# Did Kim Jong Un order the public execution of an orchestra conductor?

Tags: north-korea

In [this May, 2021 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=469kgY8vPNE), [Yeonmi Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_Yeon-mi) claims that [Kim Jong Un](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Jong-un), Supreme Leader of North Korea, recently executed an orchestra's leader for privately disagreeing with a perfomance's review.

The claim can be found [elsewere](https://slippedisc.com/2021/05/report-kim-jong-un-executes-a-conductor-in-front-of-orchestra/) as well:

> The North Korean defector Yeonmi Park has shared a report that the conductor of the Pyongyang orchestra was shot 90 times in front of the orchestra and public on the dictator’s orders. The musicians were then made to troop past his body.
>
> Apparently Kim took exception to something the conductor was reported to have said to a friend.
>
> There is no independent corroboration of this story, as yet.
>
> The conductor is named in the video as Hyun-woo Cho.
>
> UPDATE: Here is a back-up report in [South Korean media](https://www.donga.com/news/article/all/20210428/106666129/1).

Are there independent sources which support or refute this claim?

Comment: @pipe: No need to watch the video if you don't want to; OP has summarised the claim. A direct quote would help. I found her on Wikipedia, and edited in the link. YouTube tells us the video has close to 1 million views, so it is clearly notable, even if she isn't known to some people.

Comment: How would she know? She left NK a long time ago.

Comment: The SK report is quite risible in its google translation (which might contain some mistakes though). Supposedly the conductor was shot with 3 full clips from AK47-type weapons and his body became so heavy (?) it could not be lifted. There AK clips don't weight that much. The venue where this claim was published does seem [notable enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dong-a_Ilbo) though.

Comment: @Fizz, I like your improvements to the question, thank you.

Comment: @Fizz The report from South Korea cited above doesn't say the body was too heavy to lift. A translated quote instead says, "The body of 90 shots was impossibly packed, so it was treated with shovels and stoppers and carried by car."